# Multiple Popups with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a series of items within a flex container, that when clicked, trigger a popup. However, it appears that each item involves at least one function. Is it possible to have multiple popups with one function? Many thanks.

```
.flex-image {
width: 22.5%;
height: 195px;
margin: 10px;
font-size: auto;
padding: 85px;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

<div class="flex-image" onclick="myFunction()" style = "background-
image:url(Images/Sample1.jpg);"> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img 
class = "intimage" src= "Images/Sample1.jpg"> </span> </div>
<div class="flex-image" onclick="myFunction()" style = "background-
image:url(Images/Sample2.jpg);"> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img 
class = "intimage" src= "Images/Sample2.jpg"> </span></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction1() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
...
</script>
```

Is there a way to have it open the user's choice of popup without having to create a new function every time?

Comment: Generally speaking, an event variable is passed to the function handling the click. You can check `event.target` to see what item the click was triggered on. For more specifics, this question needs more information. Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: First problem, Id's must be unique, this is not the case in your mark up. There are several approaches here. You can rely on structure, relate articles with a data attribute or use a good old-fashioned link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .box{
        border:5px solid red;
        background:#000;
        padding:50px;
        height:150px;
        width:320px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-bottom:30px;

    }
    .box>h2{
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .popup{
        border:5px solid #000;
        background:red;
        padding:50px;
        height:150px;
        width:70%;
        cursor:pointer;
        position:fixed;
        top:200px;
        left:50px;
        display:none;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".box").on('click', function(){
        $(".popup").show();
   });
    $(".close").on('click', function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <h2>1</h2>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h2>2</h2>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h2>3</h2>
</div>

<div class="popup">
 <a href="#" class="close">close<a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```